# How do I move files around in Neovim using the NvimTree plugin

Tags: neovim, hotkeys

I want to be able to move files around in Neovim without typing:
`:!mv xxxx/yyyy.file xxxx/zzzz/`

I have NvimTree plugin currently installed and would like to use it since it has more information displayed to me and shows the hierarchy.

I also tried `c` and `p` to copy and paste files around but then I have to go back and clean up the file in the previous location which is a pain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way I have found to do this is by marking each file you want to move with `m`. This puts a bookmark onto your file. From anywhere perform `bmv` and you can type the location to move your file(s) to.The current directory will be conveniently prefixed before you start typing. This key combo makes for efficient use with bulk moves and single files.